# Ubuntu 14.04 RAM not usable -- mallocate problem

Tags: 14.04, server, ram, pae

I have a strange situation where my Ubuntu server (14.04) is not recognizing all of the memory installed in my server. I have a HP Proliant DL 380 G3 server (32bit) with 10 GB memory. I couldn't use memory more than 3GB. I have an installed version of Ubuntu 14.04.2 32 Bit with kernel  3.13.0-46-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP.

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       10108436 kB
MemFree:         9036220 kB

cat /boot/config-3.13.0-46-generic |grep PAE
CONFIG_X86_PAE=y
```

I tried `memtester` & also a python program to test memory and I got result-

```
sudo memtester 4G 1
pagesize is 4096
pagesizemask is 0xfffff000
bytes 0 < pagesize 4096 -- memory argument too large?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 10 GB of memory is being recognized just fine.  But you have a 32-bit OS.  This means that each user-level process (like `memtester`) only sees a 32-bit address space; inherently, no single process can access more than 4 GB of memory (and often less).

You have PAE enabled.  This means that different pieces of your 10 GB of memory can be allocated to different processes, so you can in fact use all of it - but not all by the same process.

If it's important that a single program be able to use more than 4 GB, then you need to install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

A 32-bit Operating System, unless it has full support for `PAE` (Physical Address Extension), cannot allocate more than 4GB of RAM, including the VRAM and other minor things related to the particular motherboard and I/O devices configuration: [Wikipedia: 3 GB Barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier).

`Ubuntu` has support for `PAE` on his own, so try reinstalling again forcing `PAE` in the installation options as described here: [Ubuntu.com: PAE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE)

Comment: It looks to me like PAE is working fine.  I don't think that is the issue.